# How to sign manually an exe file with developer licence for Windows 8 RT

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, certificate, code-signing, signtool

I make an exe file for Windows 8 RT. But when I want to run, show an error message:

```
"Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. ..."
```

I get a **developer licence for windows 8 RT**. With this license **visual studio 2012** can remotely deploy and run metro application in my surface.

But I want to sign manually my exe file with this certificate using **signtool.exe**:

```
signtool.exe sign -s CertStoreName -n "subject name" C:\mytest.exe
```

My problem is that I don't know the **"CertStoreName"** and **"subject name"** for my developer licence.
How can I get these names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer license just allows you to deploy and run Windows Store apps on Windows RT, while such apps are still being developed.  If you are building a Store app, you should not worry about signing your binaries yourself.  The Store signs all the contents of your app package before it is distributed to the end-users.

Desktop apps is a different story however.  Building desktop apps on Windows RT (ARM) is not supported.

Comment: I don't want to use Store. I want to run my application in my Surface. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Build your **Windows Store** app package from within Visual Studio (context menu Store->Create App Packages) and in the dialog select the option to NOT deploy to the store.  This will create the appx needed and sign it appropriately.  On the Surface, you'd then run the PowerShell script that's created when you build the package (the files for which you could copy from your desktop machine to USB and copy to the Surface)

Comment: @JimO'Neil Thanks, It works fine for my metro style app. But I want to package a C++ Native exe file that compiled for ARM, and visual studio does not support 'Create App Package' for this type of project. I want to manually do same work that visual studio done for Packaging an 'App Package'.

Comment: As @Sometimes mentioned, you can't deploy a C++ application (that is not a Windows Store application) to a Windows RT (ARM) device

Comment: finally, I use this method http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1944675 to run my exe without sign.

Comment: It's not impossible. It has been done with Office 2013 as it can only be used on the desktop on the Surface RT. They just need the certificate MS uses.