# Why Don't Windows 10 Apps Require Key-Signing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, private-key

In both iOS and Android I noticed there is a process to privately sign apps before publishing it to their respective stores.

However, in the Windows 10 Universal App Process I haven't found this to be the case. How does Microsoft get away without requiring the developer to sign their app? Or does Visual Studio / dev.windows.com somehow take care of this behind the scenes?

Comment: Related: [How to sign manually an exe file with developer licence for Windows 8 RT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018337/how-to-sign-manually-an-exe-file-with-developer-licence-for-windows-8-rt)

Answer (score 0):

When you generate an app package to upload to the Windows Store (typically via Visual Studio, I'm not actually sure if there's a command line alternative), it is signed by VS. The key is linked to your Windows Store Developer account, which is why you have to sign in to the correct dev account when building a release.

Edit: This is somewhat out of date (VS2012/Windows 8 era), but it goes into more detail (and talks about the alternatives to VS that do seem to exist - MakeCert and Pvk2Pfx): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396